# UK short-term study visa - group

Tags: uk, serbian-citizens

I am applying for a short-term study visa for a training course at the University of Kent. Two of my friends from Serbia are also accepted to the same course and applying for a visa. I have registered us as a group on the TLSContact site because the application had a question about intentions to travel with someone, and the TLSContact site required it too.

I would like to know if we have to arrive together? Because we have different travel preferences and would probably like to come to the UK separately if we get the visas.

Also, are our visa processing times dependent on when the last of the three of us does the interview?

Comment: Given that this question is about *short-term* study, voting to close it in favor of [Expatriates.SE] does not make sense.  Furthermore, the group travel and group visa application elements are more at home here than they are there.

Comment: As far as I recall, the online application asks ‘Are you travelling to the UK as part of an organised group’ and ‘Will you be travelling to the UK with someone who is not your partner, spouse, or dependent’. It depends how you interpret the latter question, but it does not say ‘will you be in the UK at the same time as people you know’. From your description of the trip, and your preference to travel separately, I’d say the answer to both is ‘No’. If you answer ‘yes’ to the second question, then IMHO you should travel together.

Answer (score 1):

While a number of you are attending the same program, you would not be considered a group, for purposes of applying fora UK visa.

The appropriate visa will depend the length of the [programme at Kent](https://www.kent.ac.uk/courses/short-term/programmes/index.html) in which you’ve enrolled. As with any university with international students, the [University of Kent](https://www.kent.ac.uk/studentimmigration/short-term%20study%20visas.html) web site offers comprehensive information on what is needed and how to proceed.

> [Short-term study visa](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/eligibility)
>
> A short-term study visa allows you to study short courses in the UK and is suitable if you are over 18. To qualify for a short-term study visa your course must be less than 6 months in duration unless you are studying an English language course of up to 11 months duration. If you will be studying a pre-sessional English course and intend to continue your studies you should [apply for entry clearance under Tier 4 (General)](https://www.kent.ac.uk/studentimmigration/prepare-tier4-application/applying-overseas.html) and not as a short-term student.